# Java c14N Canonicaliser - Attribute name order is in the wrong order

Tags: java, xml, saml, canonicalization, c14n

Java c14n Canonicalizer is switching up the attribute order of the canonicalized XML assertion.

The canonicalizer is outputting the following string post canonicaliztion:

<saml:Assertion ID="_llhn27aoVN60ug" IssueInstant="2021-11-26T22:10:37.067073Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion

However, according to the canonicalizer documentation , xmlns:saml attribute should come before the SAML: Assertion ID attribute.

This change in the ordering of the attributes is preventing the accurate calculation of the digest value.

I am using the following canonicalizer:

org.apache.xml.security.c14n.Canonicalizer

Does anyone have any idea on as to how this can be fixed ?

Comment: I don't know the solution, but I can confirm that in canonical XML, namespace declarations should precede other attributes.